# Alternative to mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I have a WordPress plugin that at one point I need to see if a certain title exists in the database.  For 2 years, this code worked fine:

```
$myposttitle= $wpdb->get_results(
 "select post_title from $wpdb->posts
  where post_title like '%".  mysql_real_escape_string($myTitle) . "%'"
);
```

However, with php 5.5. and WP 3.9.1, this causes an error because the function `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated.

Any ideas on what other function will properly escape the contents of `$myTitle` now that I can't use `mysql_real_escape_string` anymore?

Thanks

Comment: I know there is a custom php function on stackoverflow (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162491/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string-without-connecting-to-db), but I also suggest mysqli or pdo.

Comment: actually, it looks like $wpdb->prepare does the proper escaping according to this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with database in WordPress you should never use the low lever `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*` functions.

Always use `$wpdb` methods, in your case you should use [`prepare()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks):

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
  "SELECT post_title from $wpdb->posts
  WHERE post_title LIKE %s",
  "%" . $myTitle . "%"
);
```

Moreover, once you are getting a single column, you have easier life using [`get_col`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column) instead of `get_results`:

```
$myposttitle = get_col( $query );
```

Comment: Thanks... much appreciated.  However, this won't handle the escape issue I mentioned, will it?

Comment: @Allen yes, `prepare` escape the values using `mysqli_real_escape_string` (PHP 5.5 compatible) or `mysqli_real_escape_string` according to your current version of PHP.

Answer (score 8):

While the `prepare()` answer given is partially correct, if you do need a way to escape a string for an SQL statement manually, use `esc_sql()`.

For the specific case of escaping a string to be placed inside a like statement, then it should more correctly be written like this:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
  "SELECT post_title from $wpdb->posts
  WHERE post_title LIKE %s",
  "%" . $wpdb->esc_like( $myTitle ) . "%"
);
```

The $wpdb->esc_like() is necessary so as to properly escape any percent signs, underscores, or backslashes that may be in the phrase being searched for. Note that $wpdb->esc_like() does not return prepared input, it only escapes the special characters used in a LIKE. Thus, the prepare() is still needed.