# $wpdb->prepare is not working like mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: plugin-development, mysql, wpdb

I'm working on a WordPress plugin and recently I have planned to migrate from SQL to `$wpdb`. I'm using a method called `$wpdb->prepare` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string` but it does not work.
Here is what I tried:

Code:

```
echo $fetch_row;
```

Output:

> a:5:{s:9:"task_name";s:10:"Backup Now";s:9:"mechanism";s:10:"singleCall"

Code:

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string( $fetch_row )
```

Output:

> 'a:5:{s:9:\"task_name\";s:10:\"Backup Now\";s:9:\"mechanism\"

After `mysql_real_escape_string` function executed you can see the difference in the string.

I came along [this question on stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144989/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string) so I used `$wpdb->prepare($fetch_row)`
but the output did not change, it is just like the input.

Suggest me where I'm doing mistakes.

Comment: `$wpdb->prepare` is not a direct replacement for `mysql_real_escape_string`, it has more in common with `sprintf`/`printf`, and is a little more involved

Answer (score 1):

[Check the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) - `wpdb::prepare` expects the first argument to be a [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) syntax string, followed by the arguments to be injected (again, just like sprintf):

```
echo $wpdb->prepare( '%s', $fetch_row );
```